# The hardened character does not work directly with bitcoin core importdescriptors RPC

Tags: bitcoin-core, output-script-descriptors, hardened-derivation

When I `importdescriptors` to another bitcoin core wallet using the descriptor shown in the bitcoin core, the descriptor with hardened character can not used directly.

example: `importdescriptors '[{ "desc": "pkh(tpubD92TWW3UxPVt7kL1JwM6pQLqiYUotoKH5TfaKftUCtk7FkRr2iMyrKyqKr7ixPdisMZXdxQUBn2qU1X4fZyCDcYLfibLhxUjCPXiNHp6vb1/0')#vq6m7zrg", "timestamp":"now", "internal": true }]'`

bitcoin core-QT console shows error: Error: Invalid command line

`bitcoin-cli` in command line shows this error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

I have to convert `'` to `h` and regenerate checksum by hand,to this:

```
pkh(tpubD92TWW3UxPVt7kL1JwM6pQLqiYUotoKH5TfaKftUCtk7FkRr2iMyrKyqKr7ixPdisMZXdxQUBn2qU1X4fZyCDcYLfibLhxUjCPXiNHp6vb1/0h)#r7w93wm7
```

The bitcoin core shows descriptors' hardened character all use `'`, and the descriptor often uses `importdescriptors` RPC, but it's very inconvenient to use in practice. Is it possible to make bitcoin core shows the descriptors' hardened character as `h`?

Answer (score 5):

There is an [open PR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/26076) which changes the hardened character to `h`.

In some shells, you can also escape the `'` with a backslash (i.e. `\'`) and bash will no longer consider that single quote to be the end quote of the string.

In other shells, you have to use double quotes (`"`) around the entire string, but then you have to escape each internal double quote with a backslash.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I tried to add one or two backslash before `'` (i.e.`\'`,`\\'`), both in command line in mac and QT console, but it shows the same error.

Comment: @MonKong Hmm, I guess bash handles that differently from the shell that I use. I've updated the answer with a different way but requires a lot more escaping.

Comment: Never mind, I'll wait for the bitcoin core update.@Andrew Chow